# js как дождаться загрузки элемента

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom

есть такой [сайт](https://stroev.express/) и мне нужно поднять кнопку чата на 100px, ну не знаю как дождаться загрузки именно одного элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытался так:

```
window.onload = function(){
    pako = document.querySelector("body > div > div.Application__WidgetAppContainer-sc-1f2l0a1-0.dvBAhE.widget-app-container");
    pako.style.bottom = '100px';
}
```

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded`, `Promise`, `MutationObserver`. На крайняк `setTimeout`.

Comment: @NNl993 спасибо ща гляну)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Через DOMContentLoaded поставил загрузился он полностью, но он ошибку кидает Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at

Comment: По моему ошибка указывает на то что селектор - `null`, убедитесь что вы написали правильный селектор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  pako = document.querySelector("body > div > div.Application__WidgetAppContainer-sc-1f2l0a1-0.dvBAhE.widget-app-container");
  pako.style.bottom = '100px';
 

           
}, 10000)
```

Тут ждем  10 секунду

Comment: А что если у кого-то зависла сеть, и прошло **к примеру** на загрузку 11 секунд, а не меньше 10, тогда будет ошибка, можно используя `setInterval` (поставьте интервал около 200-300 миллисекунд) проверять есть ли элемент и если есть то тогда присвоить нужный стиль, а потом очистить интервал используя `clearInterval`. Я бы вам всё-таки рекомендовал использовать Promise, так будет меньше нагружен код и сам Promise довольно оптимизирован, но и вариант с `setInterval` хорош т.к. тут будет поддержка более старых браузеров.